# Is there a compact notation for replacing one element in the sequence with another element?

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

Suppose that $s = a_{0}a_{1}\ldots$ is a sequence, $i \in \mathbb{N}$, and I wish to replace $a_{i}$ with $b$. One way to write such a sequence is $a_{0}\ldots a_{i - 1}ba_{i + 1}\ldots$. This notation takes a lot of space. Is there a commonly used notation which is more compact?

Comment: depends on the context. I have seen something like $s^{(a_i\to b)}$, but you need to supplement it with a note on the intended meaning.

Comment: @trying Your proposal is likely as compact as the expression can be. The stmaryrd package has a "shortrightarrow" symbol. If you turn your comment into an answer I will accept it.